Failure while attempting to "Adding component(s) 'universe' to all repositories."
I am trying to install Putty on my Ubuntu 22.04.5 system.
The first step is:
sudo add-apt-repository universe

This fails, see error below.
Adding component(s) 'universe' to all repositories.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Ign:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Ign:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Err:4 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Err:5 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Err:6 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]

Note: I can ping the za.archive.ubuntu.com
ping za.archive.ubuntu.com
PING mirror.liquidtelecom.com (197.155.77.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mirror.liquidtelecom.com (197.155.77.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=62.5 ms
64 bytes from mirror.liquidtelecom.com (197.155.77.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=62.4 ms
64 bytes from mirror.liquidtelecom.com (197.155.77.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=62.5 ms


That specific mirror seems to be unreliable - see also Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com

Thank you for the response.
My bad I ran a simple "apt update" only to get the same error.
I will try a different mirror.
